# How to eliminate the special character ^\^@ from String in Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, replace, special-characters

My application is reading a file which contains following data:

```
MENS HEALTH^\^@ P
```

while actual text should be

```
MENS HEALTH P
```

I have already replaced the '\u0000' but still "^\" is still remaining in the string. I am not sure what is code for this characters, so I can replace it.

When I open the file in `intelliJ` editor it's displayed as FS symbol.

Please suggest how I can eliminate this.

Thanks,

Comment: It's displayed as FS because that's what it is - the ASCII "file separator". The coding is 001C.

Comment: What is the character-encoding? And what are the actual bytes? It's hard to tell what the actual data is :)

Comment: FS = `^\` = `\u001C` and NUL = `^@` = `\u0000`. `s = s.replaceAll("[\u0000\u001C ]", "");`

Comment: This should take care of business for any language characters: `str = str.replaceAll("[^ \\p{L}]", "");`. Try it against a String like: `String str = "МУЖСКОЕ ЗДОРОВЬЕ^\\^@ П";` which is `MENS HEALTH^\^@ P` but in Russian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than worry about what characters the junk consists of, remove everything that *isn't* what you want to *keep*:

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^\\w ]+", "");
```

This deletes any characters that are not *word* characters or spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression with [`String.replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) to replace these characters.

Note that backslash has a [special meaning](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html#EscapeSequences) and need to be escaped (with a backslash).

```
"my\\^@String".replaceAll("[\\\\^@]", "");
```

[*Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/rHe)